# Sound default problem (can't mute internal speakers)

Tags: audio, defaults, sound-volume, speakers

Basically, I am having problems with the sound always finding a way to come out of the speakers, which is annoying, in a work environment.

I've removed all external audio devices and set the volume on the internal speakers to 0.

I've then connected my wireless headphones. Sometimes, they lose connection and then the MacBook defaults to internal speakers, but with full volume...

It's a weird one, where this default state doesn't allow for volume adjustment (the volume icon is greyed out).

Any way to prevent the internal speakers from firing up the office? Other than going in there with fervour and installing a physical cut off switch in the speaker wires, which I am THIS close to be doing...

Comment: Cut off the plug from broken (or inexpensive) set of earbuds or headphones and stick it in the 3.5mm audio jack on the computer.

Comment: Have you done a NVRAM reset? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Comment: I'm thinking that when you connect the wireless headphones (with volume UP) and then you lose connectivity it is the same as unplugging wired headphones: the Mac goes back to playing over the speakers. So I think that is expected (tho annoying...) behavior. IconDaemon's suggestion is the one that occurred to me and has the benefit of being simple and easy.

Comment: @IconDaemon - I tried that - to no avail. It defaults to the speakers rather than getting trapped in the 3.5mm :(

Comment: @SteveChambers - It's not expected. Read my description: I have a state called "internal speakers", which I've set to 0 volume. The state it defaults to is playing through the internal speakers but it's a weird state - there is no volume control.